# Texture mapping of multiple images with PCL

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d

I spent days on PCL to code a texture mapping example. I found some examples on the web  but none of them is working.

I would appreciate to have one example working (tested) with the API textureMeshwithMultipleCameras.

The code i found is here : 
https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/tools/standalone_texture_mapping.cpp.

But the result is weird!!!